# Django 2.1.5: Storing the current username in a blog entry

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I am very new to Django and try to build a little app for my family with some basic features, one of which is a blog app. In this now I want to store the author of a blog entry in the article model to save it in the database. In the end in the blog entry I want a header that displays the author and the datetime.

I found several approaches to that but some how none of them worked for me so far. The last thing I did now was to try and grab the username in the view with requests.user.get_username() and then populate the field in my form with this string as initial value. Somehow it just doesn't come through, I always get the "field is required" error message...

Here is my blog-create-view.py:

```
def blog_create_view(request):
    user = request.user.get_username()
    data = {'author': user}
    form = BlogForm(request.POST, data)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/blog-create/thanks')
    else:
        print(form.errors)
        form = BlogForm()

    context = {
        'articleform' : form,
    }
    return render(request, "blog-create.html", context)
```

this is the form:

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title   = forms.CharField(label='',
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Titelfeld"}))
    text    = forms.CharField(
                        label='',
                        widget=forms.Textarea(
                        )
                    )
    author  = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'title',
            'text',
        ]
```

and this is the model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=1000)
    text        = models.CharField(blank=False, default='Text', max_length=10000)
    datetime    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    featured    = models.BooleanField(default='False')
    author      = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Help is much appreciated! I am getting really frustrated trying to figure this out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to add the author name as current logged in users username you can do it as follows. And remove author in the form

```
if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.author = request.user.username
        instance.save()
```

Being said that, it will be better to change the author to `foreignkey` `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and assign to the `request.user` rather than to the `username`, so that you can filter the articles by `Article.objects.filter(author=request.user)`

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much. This is so much easier than many of the solutions I found and super intuitive! Works like charm! I still wonder why my initial data didn't get passed though...

Comment: I did try the ForeignKey solution before, however when I assign in my model author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete = models.CASCADE) and use in my view instance.author = request.user, then in my template i try to get the name as {{ instance.author.username }} and get the ValueError "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'testuser'". So it does get the right username, but somehow its the wrong format?!